# Unknown object type "nil" in Secret.data.redis-password

Tags: kubernetes

I have a tool which is now available to be deployed on Kubernetes. A known person made a document on getithub where he asked to run two power shell files. [source](https://github.com/tonikautto/qse-kubernetes-minikube)

When I run first file `0-install-tools.ps1`, it installs tools like `virtualbox`, `minikube`, `helm` and `kubernetes-cli`.

When I run second file `1-Deploy-Minikube.ps1`, it is getting failed on last step where it is executing:

```
helm install -n qliksense qlik/qliksense -f values.yaml
```

The person who has created the getithub doc on the same has run it successful but am not sure why it is failing at my windows10 machine.

Following error I am getting:

> error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in Secret.data.redis-password

Can you please help me to know why it is failing at my side or there is some problem with the version these powershell files are installing ?

Hardware: 3 core and 8 GB RAM.

I am hoping a positive response from your team.

Thanks,
Rohit

I rerun powershell files several times.

Expected result is mentioned in the article I discussed in content

Answer (score 2):

set the empty properties as:'''''' instead of nil, null or ""

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. In my case solution is create new function in **_helpers.tpl**

```
{{/*
Nullable secret value
*/}}
{{- define "secretValue" -}}
    {{- $value := . }}
    {{- if $value }}
        {{- printf "%s" $value | b64enc }}
    {{- else }}
         {{- printf "%q" "" }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

then in **secret.yaml** past follow

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: common-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  REDIS_PASSWORD: {{ include "secretValue" .Values.redisPassword }}
```

result is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: common-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  REDIS_PASSWORD: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade to Helm 12.3.1 as [recently described in the project Troubleshooting](https://github.com/tonikautto/qse-kubernetes-minikube/commit/4b3c9263594ad046f83e3a7c46ccc87d9bb08488).

> This error appears during Qlik package installation, when using Helm 2.14. Issue can be reoslve by downgrading to Helm 12.3.1.
>
> `choco install kubernetes-helm --version 2.13.1 --yes --force`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to quote the secret value before encrypting it

```
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.secretEnv }}
{{ $key  }}: {{ $val | quote | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```